# unable to get the odds of a user- bayes theorm

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, probability, bayesian, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to solve the question which is quite basic using confusion matrix but my solution is not matching the correct solution.

Q: Let's say we have a drug test that can accurately identify the users of a drug 99% of the time, and accurately has a negative result for 99% of non-users. But only 0.3% of the overall users use this drug.

What are the odds of someone being an actual user of the drug given that they tested positive?

Also, is `TP / (TP + FN)` is same as `P(A) P(B|A)/P(B)` ?

My Approach:

```
                                TP      TN        Total
Users       Predicted positive   29.7      0.3       30
Non-Users   Predicted negative   99.7   9870.3     9970
                                129.4   9870.6    10000
```

From the above data, I got : 29.7/129.4 = 0.2295208655 around 22.95%

But the solution states : 22.8% . I'm confused. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: There's no programming involved here.  Maybe try [stats.se]?

Comment: What you do looks good, i'm almost 100% sure. The solution seems wrong. Besides that, Daniel is correct

Comment: @DanielF Thanks Daniel. Posted!

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak Thank You for looking into it. The approach which was given was something like this - P(B) is 1.3% ( 0.99*0.003 + 0.01*0.997)  So, P(B|A) = P(A) P(B|A) / P(B) = 0.003*0.99 / 0.013 = 0.228 . So, '22.8%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :

The approach which was given was something like this - P(B) is 1.3% ( 0.99*0.003 + 0.01*0.997) So, P(B|A) = P(A) P(B|A) / P(B) = 0.003*0.99 / 0.013 = 0.228 . So, '22.8%'

But they have rounded the number to 1.3% instead of 1.294% and that's why the value is different!!